# How to create an MPI group with spawned processes?

Tags: python, mpi, grouping, spawn, mpi4py

I am spawning mpi processes with

```
# Master side
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, ["worker.py"], maxprocs=2)
```

on the master side and

```
# Worker side
comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
workerComm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
```

on the worker side. I am able to send data back and forth using point-to-point communication as well as collective communications. I am able to create groups on the worker side using the `workerComm` with

```
newGroup = workerComm.group.Incl([0])
newComm = workerComm.Create_group(newGroup)
```

But how is it possible to create a group with the *master* and *worker* side in a way that I can use collective communications from the *master* side with only a subset of workers?

Comment: If you want an inter communicator, you can `MPI_Comm_split(comm, ...)` use `color=0` for the tasks that should be in the new communicator and `color=MPI_UNDEFINED` fir the others.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you again for the answer. If you post it then I will accept it.